# How to fetch the data in the mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb

How to fetch the data from the json file using mongoshell

I want to fecch the Data by `policyID` 
Say in the json file I sent the PolicyID is 3148

I tried could of ways to write the command but say 0 rows fetched.

```
db.GeneralLiability.find({"properties.id":"21281"})
db.GeneralLiability.find({properties:{_id:"21281"}})
```

Do i need to set any thing else?index,cursors etc?

Sample json

```
{
    "session": {
        "data": {
            "account": {
            "properties": {
            "userName": "abc.com",
            "_dateModified": "2014-10-01",
            "_manuscript": "Carrier_New_Rules_2_1_0",
            "_engineVersion": "2.0.0",
            "_cultureCode": "en-US",
            "_cultureName": "United States [english]",
            "_context": "Underwriter",
            "_caption": "Carrier New  Rules  (2.1.0)",
            "_id": "p1CEB08012E51477C9CD0E89FE77F5E51"
        },
         "properties": {
        "_xmlns:xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
        "_xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
        "_id": "3148",
        "_HistoryID": "5922",
        "_Type": "onset",
        "_Datestamp": "2014-10-01T04:46:33",
        "_TransactionType": "New",
        "_EffectiveDate": "2014-01-01",
        "_Charge": "1599",
        "_TransactionGroup": "t4CE4FA751F9C400D9007E692A883DA66",
        "_PolicyID": "3148",
        "_Index": "1",
        "_Count": "1",
        "_Sequence": "1"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: use mongoimport to import your json into a database and collection. Then run the db service (mongod), and on then on a separate terminal, you can query your collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return the document with `_PolicyID = "3148"`:

```
db.GeneralLiability.find({
  "session._PolicyID": "3148"
}).pretty();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues in your document formatting.  First off I am pretty sure that using underscores are reserved for mongo (I could be wrong).  Either way it is bad form.  I have restructured your data for you.  I am not sure why you wanted to nest your data so much, but I am guessing you had a good reason for it.

You will notice that I am using the ObjectID from Mongo for my _id:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56e1c1f53bac31a328e3682b"), 
"session" : {
    "data" : {
        "account" : {
            "properties" : {
                "xmlns:xsd" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", 
                "xmlns:xsi" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", 
                "HistoryID" : "5922", 
                "Type" : "onset", 
                "Datestamp" : "2014-10-01T04:46:33", 
                "TransactionType" : "New", 
                "EffectiveDate" : "2014-01-01", 
                "Charge" : "1599", 
                "TransactionGroup" : "t4CE4FA751F9C400D9007E692A883DA66", 
                "PolicyID" : "3148", 
                "Index" : "1", 
                "Count" : "1", 
                "Sequence" : "1"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now if you run this command it will return your document:

```
{ "session.data.account.properties.PolicyID": "3148" }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response i am not nesting the data.I have a req where the data is in xml format and we converted it into json format.Each xml is one document.The above code i sent is just a snippet of code. there are around 400 lines of code.Now my req is each document has a ID which can be same for in the multiple documents.Now i want to fetch the data by ID ,on doing so all the associated documents should be displayed.I am not sure how to upload the json file here so that u get the clear idea..

Comment: FYI: Except for the reserved `_id` [you can add as many underscores as you want](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#field-names).